# CSS Transitions Problem in Sidebar using React

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I'm working to my portfolio with responsiveness using react.js, CSS, Bootstrap. were when the small screen the menu for the sidebar will show.

but the problem is when I click na menu to open the sidebar the transition is not working which I want that the transition will slide effect starting from left everytime I open or closed.

My css module code:

```
.sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: -300px;
  background: var(--gray);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar.open {
  left: -250px;
  transition: all ease-in-out.5;
}
```

here's my Navbar.jsx code:

```
<div className={`d-lg-none align-self-center`} onClick={ShowNav}>
  <RiMenu4Fill className={style.menu}/></div>

    <ul>
      <li><a href='#home'>Home</a></li>
      <li><a href='#skill'>Skills</a></li>
      <li><a href='#contact'>contacts</a></li>
    </ul>


    {isShow && (
    <hr/>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#home'>Home</a></li>
      <li><a href='#skill'>Skills</a></li>
      <li><a href='#contact'>contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
    )}

</div>
```

Comment: Please have a closer look at the editor. Formatting code isn't difficult. Also take the [tour].

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)